# вылетает OutOfMemory

Tags: java, android

есть такой код, вылетает OOM, по логам смотрел при стррте уже 30 мб heap загружено при нажатии на кнопку, еще столько же приходит, откуда такие цифры?

```
public class Test_Fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

public static final String EXTRA_ITEM_TEST =
        "com.just_app.diplom.item";
private ImageView view_1;
private ImageView view_2;
private ImageView view_3;
private ImageView view_4;
private TextView textViewTestWord, scoreTextView;
private String mItemQuestions;
private Subject_Question mSubQuest;
private ObjectMapper mapper;
private AssetManager mgr;
private int i = 0;
private int score = 0;
private String mQuestion;
private Uri imgUri;
private boolean flag_answer = false;

public static Test_Fragment newInstance(String item) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(EXTRA_ITEM_TEST, item);
    Test_Fragment test_fragment = new Test_Fragment();
    test_fragment.setArguments(args);
    return test_fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mItemQuestions = (String) getArguments()
            .getSerializable(EXTRA_ITEM_TEST);
    LoadQuestionTask loadQuestionTask = new LoadQuestionTask();
    loadQuestionTask.execute(mItemQuestions);
    try {
        mSubQuest = loadQuestionTask.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class LoadQuestionTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Subject_Question> {
    @Override
    protected Subject_Question doInBackground(String... params) {
        mgr = getActivity().getAssets();
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream;
            inputStream = mgr.open(mItemQuestions);
            mSubQuest = mapper.readValue(inputStream, Subject_Question.class);
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mSubQuest;
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
    init(v);
    onChangeQuestion();
    return v;
}

public void onChangeQuestion() {
    mgr = getActivity().getAssets();
    Collections.shuffle(mSubQuest.content);
    if (mSubQuest.content != null && i < mSubQuest.content.size()) {
        try {
            imgUri = Uri.parse(mSubQuest.content.get(i).answer_1);
            view_1.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(imgUri));
            view_1.setTag(mSubQuest.content.get(i).answer_1);

            Uri imgUri_2 = Uri.parse(mSubQuest.content.get(i).answer_2);
            view_2.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(imgUri_2));
            view_2.setTag(mSubQuest.content.get(i).answer_2);

            Uri imgUri_3 = Uri.parse(mSubQuest.content.get(i).answer_3);
            view_3.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(imgUri_3));
            view_3.setTag(mSubQuest.content.get(i).answer_3);

            Uri imgUri_4 = Uri.parse(mSubQuest.content.get(i).answer_4);
            view_4.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(imgUri_4));
            view_4.setTag(mSubQuest.content.get(i).answer_4);

            mQuestion = mSubQuest.content.get(i).question;
            textViewTestWord.setText(mQuestion);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public Drawable getDrawable(Uri img) throws IOException {
    InputStream stream = mgr.open(
            img.getPath().substring("/android_asset/".length()));
    Drawable drawableView = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, null);
    stream.close();
    return drawableView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (i < mSubQuest.content.size())
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_1:
                String srcimage = (String) view_1.getTag();
                flag_answer = srcimage.equals(mSubQuest.content.get(i).correct_answer);
                custom_Toast(v);
                break;
            case R.id.button_2:
                String srcimage_2 = (String) view_2.getTag();
                flag_answer = srcimage_2.equals(mSubQuest.content.get(i).correct_answer);
                custom_Toast(v);
                break;
            case R.id.button_3:
                String srcimage_3 = (String) view_3.getTag();
                flag_answer = srcimage_3.equals(mSubQuest.content.get(i).correct_answer);
                custom_Toast(v);
                break;
            case R.id.button_4:
                String srcimage_4 = (String) view_4.getTag();
                flag_answer = srcimage_4.equals(mSubQuest.content.get(i).correct_answer);
                custom_Toast(v);
                break;
            case R.id.next:
                i++;
                onChangeQuestion();
                lock_button(true);
        }
}

public void init(View v) {
    view_1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    view_2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.button_2);
    view_3 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.button_3);
    view_4 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.button_4);
    Button next = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.next);
    scoreTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.scoreTextView);
    textViewTestWord = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewTestWord);
    view_1.setOnClickListener(this);
    view_2.setOnClickListener(this);
    view_3.setOnClickListener(this);
    view_4.setOnClickListener(this);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void custom_Toast(View toast) {
    String[] correct_answer = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_correct_answer);
    String[] incorrect_answer = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_incorrect_answer);
    List correct_answer_list = Arrays.asList(correct_answer);
    List incorrect_answer_list = Arrays.asList(incorrect_answer);
    Collections.shuffle(correct_answer_list);
    Collections.shuffle(incorrect_answer_list);
    Random random = new Random();
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_layout,
            (ViewGroup) toast.findViewById(R.id.toast_layout));
    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_text);
    if (flag_answer) {
        lock_button(false);
        scoreTextView.setText("" + ++score);
        text.setText(String.valueOf(correct_answer_list.get(random.nextInt(5))));
    } else {
        text.setText(String.valueOf(incorrect_answer_list.get(random.nextInt(5))));
    }
    Toast tost = new Toast(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    tost.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    tost.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    tost.setView(layout);
    tost.show();
}

public void lock_button(boolean type_lock) {
    view_1.setClickable(type_lock);
    view_2.setClickable(type_lock);
    view_3.setClickable(type_lock);
    view_4.setClickable(type_lock);
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего дело в картинках. Попробуйте их не устанавливать и должно перестать падать. Решить можно грузя их библиотекой типа UIL, коя умеет уменьшать размер картинок под размер контейнера

Comment: не подскажите, как лучше тогда в этом случае использовать UIL, ведь ей на вход надо давать уже готовые фото, а у меня получается, что я ссылки на фото получаю из json файла, потом обрезаю их, так как они лежат в assets, и только  потом, getDrawable(imgUri_4), присваиваю в imageview?
если можно хотелось бы получить рекомендации по улучшению чистоты кода..

Comment: @Сергей, из `assets` может библиотека картинки устанавливать так: `imageLoader.displayImage("assets://image.png", imageView);`

Comment: спасибо, помогло!